# bufferapp always returns me a NULL access_token

Tags: php, encoding

Here is the code:

```
        $client_id = '';
       $client_secret = '';
          $callback_url = '';


      $buffer = new BufferApp($client_id, $client_secret, $callback_url);

     if (!$buffer->ok) {
    echo '<a href="' . $buffer->get_login_url() . '">Connect to Buffer!</a>';
} else {
    //this pulls all of the logged in user's profiles
    $profiles = $buffer->go('/profiles');

    if (is_array($profiles)) {
        foreach ($profiles as $profile) {
            //this creates a status on each one
            $buffer->go('/updates/create', array('text' => 'My first status update from bufferapp-php worked!', 'profile_ids[]' => $profile->id));
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['code']))
{
  var_dump($_SESSION['oauth']['buffer']['access_token']);
}
```

it is an example code, I had to be returned the access_token, but it is NULL

trying to log in I'm redirected to the bufferapp' site, give the access, then I'm redirected back and it is NULL

what's the problem ?

thanks in advance)

the bufferapi code :

```
class BufferApp {
    private $client_id;
    private $client_secret;
    private $code;
    private $access_token;

    private $callback_url;
    private $authorize_url = 'https://bufferapp.com/oauth2/authorize';
    private $access_token_url = 'https://api.bufferapp.com/1/oauth2/token.json';
    private $buffer_url = 'https://api.bufferapp.com/1';

    public $ok = false;

    private $endpoints = array(
        '/user' => 'get',

        '/profiles' => 'get',
        '/profiles/:id/schedules/update' => 'post', // Array schedules [0][days][]=mon, [0][times][]=12:00
        '/profiles/:id/updates/reorder' => 'post',  // Array order, int offset, bool utc
        '/profiles/:id/updates/pending' => 'get',
        '/profiles/:id/updates/sent' => 'get',
        '/profiles/:id/schedules' => 'get',
        '/profiles/:id' => 'get',

        '/updates/:id/update' => 'post',                        // String text, Bool now, Array media ['link'], ['description'], ['picture'], Bool utc
        '/updates/create' => 'post',                                // String text, Array profile_ids, Aool shorten, Bool now, Array media ['link'], ['description'], ['picture']
        '/updates/:id/destroy' => 'post',
        '/updates/:id' => 'get',

        '/links/shares' => 'get',
    );

    public $errors = array(
        'invalid-endpoint' => 'The endpoint you supplied does not appear to be valid.',

        '403' => 'Permission denied.',
        '404' => 'Endpoint not found.',
        '405' => 'Method not allowed.',
        '1000' => 'An unknown error occurred.',
        '1001' => 'Access token required.',
        '1002' => 'Not within application scope.',
        '1003' => 'Parameter not recognized.',
        '1004' => 'Required parameter missing.',
        '1005' => 'Unsupported response format.',
        '1010' => 'Profile could not be found.',
        '1011' => 'No authorization to access profile.',
        '1012' => 'Profile did not save successfully.',
        '1013' => 'Profile schedule limit reached.',
        '1014' => 'Profile limit for user has been reached.',
        '1020' => 'Update could not be found.',
        '1021' => 'No authorization to access update.',
        '1022' => 'Update did not save successfully.',
        '1023' => 'Update limit for profile has been reached.',
        '1024' => 'Update limit for team profile has been reached.',
        '1028' => 'Update soft limit for profile reached.',
        '1030' => 'Media filetype not supported.',
        '1031' => 'Media filesize out of acceptable range.',
    );

    public $responses = array(
        '403' => 'Permission denied.',
        '404' => 'Endpoint not found.',
        '405' => 'Method not allowed.',
        '500' => 'An unknown error occurred.',
        '403' => 'Access token required.',
        '403' => 'Not within application scope.',
        '400' => 'Parameter not recognized.',
        '400' => 'Required parameter missing.',
        '406' => 'Unsupported response format.',
        '404' => 'Profile could not be found.',
        '403' => 'No authorization to access profile.',
        '400' => 'Profile did not save successfully.',
        '403' => 'Profile schedule limit reached.',
        '403' => 'Profile limit for user has been reached.',
        '404' => 'Update could not be found.',
        '403' => 'No authorization to access update.',
        '400' => 'Update did not save successfully.',
        '403' => 'Update limit for profile has been reached.',
        '403' => 'Update limit for team profile has been reached.',
        '403' => 'Update soft limit for profile reached.',
        '400' => 'Media filetype not supported.',
        '400' => 'Media filesize out of acceptable range.',
    );

    function __construct($client_id = '', $client_secret = '', $callback_url = '') {
        if ($client_id) $this->set_client_id($client_id);
        if ($client_secret) $this->set_client_secret($client_secret);
        if ($callback_url) $this->set_callback_url($callback_url);

        if ($_GET['code']) {
            $this->code = $_GET['code'];
            $this->create_access_token_url();
        }

        $this->retrieve_access_token();
    }

    function go($endpoint = '', $data = '') {
        if (in_array($endpoint, array_keys($this->endpoints))) {
            $done_endpoint = $endpoint;
        } else {
            $ok = false;

            foreach (array_keys($this->endpoints) as $done_endpoint) {
                if (preg_match('/' . preg_replace('/(\:\w+)/i', '(\w+)', str_replace('/', '\/', $done_endpoint)) . '/i', $endpoint, $match)) {
                    $ok = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!$ok) return $this->error('invalid-endpoint');
        }

        if (!$data || !is_array($data)) $data = array();
        $data['access_token'] = $this->access_token;

        $method = $this->endpoints[$done_endpoint]; //get() or post()
        return $this->$method($this->buffer_url . $endpoint . '.json', $data);
    }

    function store_access_token() {
        $_SESSION['oauth']['buffer']['access_token'] = $this->access_token;
    }

    function retrieve_access_token() {
        $this->access_token = $_SESSION['oauth']['buffer']['access_token'];

        if ($this->access_token) {
            $this->ok = true;
        }
    }

    function error($error) {
        return (object) array('error' => $this->errors[$error]);
    }

    function create_access_token_url() {
        $data = array(
            'code' => $this->code,
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'client_id' => $this->client_id,
            'client_secret' => $this->client_secret,
            'redirect_uri' => $this->callback_url,
        );

        $obj = $this->post($this->access_token_url, $data);
        $this->access_token = $obj->access_token;

        $this->store_access_token();
    }

    function req($url = '', $data = '', $post = true) {
        if (!$url) return false;
        if (!$data || !is_array($data)) $data = array();

        $options = array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, CURLOPT_HEADER => false);

        if ($post) {
            $options += array(
                CURLOPT_POST => $post,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data
            );
        } else {
            $url .= '?' . http_build_query($data);
        }

        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
        $rs = curl_exec($ch);

        $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ($code >= 400) {
            return $this->error($code);
        }

        return json_decode($rs);
    }

    function get($url = '', $data = '') {
        return $this->req($url, $data, false);
    }

    function post($url = '', $data = '') {
        return $this->req($url, $data, true);
    }

    function get_login_url() {
        return $this->authorize_url . '?'
        . 'client_id=' . $this->client_id
        . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode($this->callback_url)
        . '&response_type=code';
    }

    function set_client_id($client_id) {
        $this->client_id = $client_id;
    }

    function set_client_secret($client_secret) {
        $this->client_secret = $client_secret;
    }

    function set_callback_url($callback_url) {
        $this->callback_url = $callback_url;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the BufferApp code? It's difficult to diagnose otherwise.

Comment: @suspectus I have updated, please check it, thank you